# When $(f(x)-\mathbb{E}(f(x))$ belongs to $X^{*}$ when $f\in X^{*}$

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm a little bit confused and I know that the question is trivial but I can't find a good argument for the following assumption.

Lets say that we have a gaussian measure $\mu$ on a separable banach space $X$ with 
mean

$a_{\mu}(f)=\int_{X}f(x)\mu(dx)$ ,$f\in X^{*}$

and covariance

$Q_{\mu}(f,f)=\int_{X}(f(x)-a_{\mu}(f))^{2}\mu(dx)$,$f\in X^{*}$

My question is the following:

if we have that a functional $f\in X^{*}$  then $f-a_{\mu}(f)$ is going to be in $X^{*}$??

Because I have a mapping $j:X^{*}\rightarrow L^{2}(X,\mu)$ and I want to see if it's an inclusion map.

Comment: Thanks for editing.  How does $f-a_\mu(f)$ act on $X$?  It looks like the difference between a functional and a number.

Comment: Maybe $f-a_{\mu}(f)$ it's a transfer of f because we remove the value $a_{\mu}(f)$.Yes it's a difference between a functional and a number but I don't really know how to show that $f-a_{\mu}(f)$ belongs in $X^{*}$ . A first thought is to show that $f-a_{\mu}(f)$ is also a functional in $X^{*}$ , e.i is bounded , linear and belong at $X$?

Comment: Well, I don't know how to add numbers and functionals, but that's what you seem to want.  I'd guess the answer to your question is "No, $\mathbb C$ (or $\mathbb R$) is not contained in $X*$, so it does not make sense to ask about the properties of $f-a_\mu(f)$."